# Will Windows fixmbr upset Ubuntu

Tags: boot, dual-boot, mbr

I have a home PC dual booting Windowx XP with Ubuntu 12.04.
I have been using GParted and changing some sizes of various partitions to use some extra available free space.

It occurred to me that if I upset anything I can rescue the Windows MBR using various approaches including the Windows/DOS FDISK method, but would that effectively destroy Ubuntu/Grub boot loading by resetting the boot record back to the original Windows XP entry only?

Perhaps it's a strange question and I hope that makes sense.

Comment: It's nt strange, just a little overdramatic, and yes, it will render Ubuntu unbootable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use the `fixmbr` command in Windows, then assuming it succeeds, it will write the Windows boot loader to the Master Boot Record. That will overwrite the part of GRUB (Ubuntu's boot loader) that is installed to the MBR, and you will not have an option to boot Ubuntu.

However, that's not usually a big problem, as it's quite easy to put Ubuntu's boot loader back in the MBR:

- [How can I repair grub? (How to get Ubuntu back after installing Windows?)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows)
  (Applies even if GRUB is broken due to reasons unrelated to a recent installation of Windows--including `fixmbr` having been run--or even totally unrelated to Windows.)
- [Grub2/Installing: Fixing a Broken System](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing#Fixing_a_Broken_System) (in the Ubuntu documentation wiki)

These methods will also often fix the same kinds of problems you might use `fixmbr` to fix. They will facilitate Ubuntu and Windows bootiing; `fixmbr`, at least as it is normally used, installs the Windows boot loader to the MBR, and results in a configuration that only boots Windows.

For boot problems, you may be interested in [the Boot Repair utility](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair).

If the problem is that the installed Windows system doesn't come up in the GRUB menu when you turn on your computer, it might be sufficient to run

```
sudo update-grub
```

in the Ubuntu system. (You can also run `sudo os-prober` but that should get run automatically when you run `sudo update-grub`.)